# adding short codes to the homepage template dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im building a bespoke word press theme and am working on a section for testimonials Ive created a slider and it works fine however the client would rather a different type of functionality. im thinking it would be easier if i could just create a place in the admin where a short code can be added which is then put on the home page.

the only way i can think of doing this is with the customizer api however my php knowledge is not the best and i cannot think of how to put together a piece of code to display whatever shortcode i add to my customizer setting

here is my attempt (imaging everything is set up in customizer to allow it to work )

```
echo do_shortcode( echo get_theme_mode('testimonials'));
```

but i dont think you can echo in an echo

Comment: You wouldn’t need to do echo inside echo, if you’re expecting get_theme_mode to echo something out that means it’s returning the value so just remove the second echo and that will parse in the return to the do shortcode function

Comment: @GlenElkins that just prints the shortcode to the home page i need the wp function do_shortcode to run before hand

Comment: its all good i worked it out thankyou for your help